# About the difference between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, definition

Reading about [canonical forms for real matrices](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/labute/courses/251.04/jordan3.pdf), I have found this:

> Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ real matrix and let $T=T_A:\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1} \to \mathbb{R}^{n\times 1} $ be the associated linear operator.

I understand that $\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ is the space of $1-$column matrices with $n$ rows, of the form $[x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n]^T$, that usually, I identify with the vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

What is the utility of distinguish between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1} $?

Comment: To make clear that these are column vectors? Many in statistics use vectors for row vectors.

Comment: You can distinguish between $\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{1\times n}$ then. Sometimes, that's useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this notation, every "space" being considered is of the form $\Bbb R^{m\times n}$. Otherwise, the author has to separately define $\Bbb R^n$.

I think most people like this distinction because we treat the underlying vector space $\Bbb R^n$ in a fundamentally different way than we treat the matrix space $\Bbb R^{m\times n}$. Obviously, this author didn't find that to be a useful distinction to make.

As the comments mention, there's also the matter of distinguishing row/column vectors.